# Javascript/jQuery Toggling Sidebar

Tags: javascript

Just wondering, does anyone know any good toggling sidebars?

Like, it sits on the side of the screen, and you hide it by clicking a arrow, and you can make it show again, by clicking the arrow.

Anyone know any good ones?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a very simple side navigation menu using Jquery.

[Demo](http://www.andrewsellick.com/examples/sliding-side-bar-scriptaculous/#)

Tutorial: [sliding-side-bar-scriptaculous](http://www.parrisstudios.com/?p=339)